# A problem regarding the value of the derivative of a real valued function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Does there exist a differentiable function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \lt 1$ whenever $|x-y| \lt 1$ but $|f'(x)|$ is not necessarily less than or equal to $1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R ?$

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ Actually,I have thought of a lot of examples specially manipulating the trigonometric functions, but I couldn't find anything to assert a positive answer to the above question .

Obviously, the converse is true and no linear functions can satisfy the above requirements.

A small hint is warmly appreciated.

Comment: *“... specially manipulating the trigonometric functions ...”* – did you try $f(x) = a \sin(bx)$ for suitable $a, b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac 1  3 \sin (x^{2})$ is an example. Take $x=\sqrt {2n\pi}$ to see that the derivative is not even bounded. But $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \frac 1  3 +\frac 1  3  <1$ for all $x,y$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** If you design a function $f$ whose codomain is an interval with a length less than one (such as $[0,1/2]$), then you will have that $|f(x)-f(y)|<1$ for *all* $x$ and $y$, not just when $|x-y|<1$. Can you design a function whose codomain fits inside a tiny interval, but which has derivatives larger than $1$ in magnitude? (Your intuition to try trig functions seems to me like a good idea.)